# Karate-Robot: How to scroll through a datagrid element?

Tags: karate

I have been using the Karate framework Robot component for desktop UI automation. With it, I need to click on a button in each row item of a data grid and using `click()` doesn't work when the item is not in view/is offscreen. As such I'm trying to figure out how to scroll down to the items I need so I can click the button. I noticed with the driver there is an option to `scroll()` but I haven't been able to find one with Robot.

Is there a workaround for this or are there plans to add a `scroll()` function for karate-robot in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll certainly sounds like it may be missing from the existing API. Please do consider investigating and contributing to the code, which will just make it faster to release.

Meanwhile here are the possible workarounds:

- see if using the TAB key auto-scrolls to the element
- if you get a reference to the button you can call `invoke()` on it which is supported by a [range of windows components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/invoke-a-control-using-ui-automation)

P.S. please do consider contributing code, the code base is actually quite simple. And here is where you can implement the `Scroll` pattern: [link](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/v1.0.1/karate-robot/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/robot/win/Pattern.java#L39).

Comment: I was able to do something similar to the TAB key with Key.DOWN as a work around for now. I'll try and see if I can contribute to the code when I have some time in the near future. Thank you!